# Can't install Twillio package at package manage console in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#

I want to use twilio package in visual studio 2015. So I typed `Install-Package Twilio` in the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio 2015.

Result in package manager console:

> Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Twilio'
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - Install-Package Twilio
> - 
> - CategoryInfo   : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

How can I fix it?

Comment: Twilio has one "l"

Answer (score 1):

try to use this command for the latest package

```
Install-Package Twilio -Version 5.28.0
```

from the package manager console

your problem is that you type two letters 'l' in the package name